# How can I test my express/typeorm app with mocha?

Tags: typescript, testing, mocha.js, typeorm

This is my index.ts

```js
import "reflect-metadata";
import {createConnection, Server} from "typeorm";
import express from "express";
import * as bodyParser from "body-parser";
import routes from "./routes/routes";
import cors from 'cors';

const init = () => createConnection().then( async () => {
    
    const app = express();
    // create express app
    app.use(bodyParser.json());
    app.use(cors());

    // register express routes from defined application routes
    app.use("/", routes);
    app.listen(3000);

    console.log("Express server has started on port 3000.");

    return app;

}).catch(error => console.log(error));

export default init;
```

And I want to import init inside my tests,

```js
import chai from 'chai';
import chaiHttp from 'chai-http';

import init from '..';

chai.use(chaiHttp);
chai.should();

let app;

describe("TESTS", () => {
    before(async () => {
        app = await init();
    });

    describe("GET /posts", () => {
        //Test to get all posts
        it("Should get all posts", (done) => {
            chai.request(app)
                .get('/posts')
                .end((err, response) => {
                    response.should.have.status(200);
                    response.body.should.be.a('object');
                    done();
                });
        });
    });
});
```

This code is working, but I want to clese the connection at the end of the test whit `server.close` (server is the returned object of app.listen()) But I don know how to export that object, when I try something like

```js
return {app: app, server: server}
```

I get an error when I try to use it inside my tests.

```
Property 'app' does not exist on type 'void | { app: Express; server: Server; }'.
```

I try to specify the return type of init() but I get errors... I think I don't know how to do it.

Comment: It's your use of `catch`. `Promise.protoype.catch` receives an error and handles it by returning a fallback value. `console.log()` returns `void` so type return type of `init` becomes `typeof app | void`

Comment: can I place all the content inside a try/catch block? and fix the problem @AluanHaddad (Sorry if my english isn't the best)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it.
Thank you [@Aluan Haddad](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1915893/aluan-haddad) you guide my to the right path.

I use try catch inside the function and change some small things.

```
const init = createConnection().then( async () => {
    try {
        const app = express();
        // create express app
        app.use(bodyParser.json());
        app.use(cors());

        // register express routes from defined application routes
        app.use("/", routes);
        const server = app.listen(3000);

        console.log("Express server has started on port 3000.");

        return {app, server};
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
    }
});
```

```
describe("TESTS", () => {
    before(async function() {
        console.log("Before executed")
        const appData = await init;
        app = appData.app;
        server = appData.server;
    });

    after(() => {
        server.close();
        console.log("After executed")
    });
}
```

If I'm making something wrong plis tell me

Comment: If I place a catch at the end (``catch(e => console.log(e))``) I'm changing the return tipe of init(). That is what was causing problems